# Issues with theme after updating to the new android studio artic fox (2020.3.1)

Tags: android-studio

Please understand that I started to use this program with almost no prior knowledge of java let alone designing an app.
So thing is that after updating to the version, it seems that the plugins(?) for the themes.xml dont work anymore. The error messages tell me that resouces are missing and honestly I dont know what this means or how to fix it.
Down below are the codes and a picture.
Thank you

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.listest" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

[The error message and the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgE3u.png)

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
```

You have not the color "colorPrimaryVariant"
you can add it or replace it with another one, for example:

```
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/purple_700</item>
```